# Display a Single Parent object row in a table format, each column displayed in a unique row

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want the ability to display a single row as a single column with each field in a separate row with their labels (only one record would be retrieved), unable to use PageBlockTable here, is there a `<apex:row>` alternative to `<apex:column>`?

Answer (score 1):

The `<apex:pageBlockSection />` renders as a table. One option would be to set it to render just one column (of two cells each row) and use the `outputField` tag to render the label and the text for each field of your object.

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:outputField value="{!yourObject.Field1__c}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!yourObject.Field2__c}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!yourObject.Field3__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native visualforce alternative to that. You can write your own HTML/CSS to achieve that instead. Also check [apex:panelGrid](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm) and see if that works for you.